# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at HTMLButtonElement.store_val1 (Intersection.html:84:46)
store_val1 @ Intersection.html:84

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr3.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < arr3.length; k++) {
            a = arr3[i][j];
            b = arr3[i + 1][k]; // 84:46
            console.log(b);
            if (a == b) {
                arr4.push(a);
                console.log('Yes');
                // j++;
            }
        }
        k = 0;
    }
    j = 0;
}
```

Comment: what is `arr3` ? The error just mean it's undefined. If you only have 3 items, and you use 3+1, there won't be such an item in the array. So you need to do conditional check there

Comment: arr3 is an array of arrays.For ex: arr3 = [ [1,2,3],[3,5,6]]

Comment: This line:: `b = arr3[i+1][k]; // 84:46` will cause this error every time you run this code.  Since the loop only stops when `i >= arr.length`, the last iteration will always attempt to go past the end of the array.

Comment: @Tibrogargan What can be the solution?

Comment: Maybe stop when i = length - 1. Need more context on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JBallin This part of the code is actually meant to check every same element in the nested arrays present in an array such as [ [1,2,3],[3,5,6]] and if found, store it in a new array

Comment: I have the same issue as @JBallin.   We don't need an explanation of the intent of the individual lines of code, we need to know what problem you're trying to solve.  looks like some sort of duplicate detection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do conditional check on the error line.

e.g.

```
const b = arr3[i + 1] ? arr3[i+1][k] : "some other value if undefined"
```